# Why is my CountDownLatch behaving differently in test run via docker build?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit, dockerfile

I have created 2 separate microservices that communicate using Apache Kafka. One is called Producer, the other is called Consumer. Both microservices have their own tests that pass no matter how I run them (Run Test, mvn clean install...) and I also test Kafka using Embedded Kafka, so my tests don't rely on presence of any other systems such as separate Kafka broker or DB being online. I wanted to create a docker image of both microservices, but when running `docker build` on Producer's DOCKERFILE, one test during `mvn clean package` throws error and the process fails. During this test, a message is sent to EmbeddedKafka, and another Class (TestConsumer) with KafkaListener is consuming this message. This class contains CountDownLatch, with countDown being triggered with any message being consumed.

```
public class TestConsumer {

    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${test.kafka.topic.name}",
            containerFactory = "embeddedKafkaListenerContainerFactory",
            groupId = "Test_Group")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?, Payload> consumerRecord) {
        // Receiving consumerRecord.value();

        log.info("DEBUG CONSUMER getLatch before countdown" + getLatch());
        latch.countDown();
        log.info("DEBUG CONSUMER getLatch after countdown" + getLatch());
    }

    public void resetLatch() {
        latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    }

    public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }
```

Test Class awaits this, and asserts message being received based on this latch, this is where the test fails.

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles({ "test" })
@EnableKafka
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = { "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092", "port=9092" })
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
class EmbeddedKafkaTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestConsumer consumer;

    @Autowired
    private TestProducer producer;

    Payload testPayload = TestPayload.getTestPayload();

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        consumer.resetLatch();
    }

    @Test
    void whenSendingWithCustomSerDe_thenMessagePojoReceived() throws Exception {

        producer.send(topic, testPayload);

        boolean messageConsumed = consumer.getLatch().await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        log.info("DEBUG TEST consumer.getLatch after await " + consumer.getLatch());

        assertTrue(messageConsumed);  // <- THIS ASSERTION FAILS

        assertEquals(testPayload.getName(), consumer.getPayload().getName());
    }
```

When I set up additional logs to print out latch information at various stages, I was surprised to find out that when I log the latch from test class and the TestConsumer class, I get 2 different IdentityHashCodes and different values when executed as part of the docker build (TestConsumer logs show the latch going down to 0, but the latch from test class logs accessed via `consumer.getLatch()` is not changing), and just one IdentityHashCode with corresponding expected value if I run the tests manually. Could someone briefly explain this behavior to me? I would prefer if the test could behave the same way in all cases, preferably with just one IdentityHashCode and same value across all classes peeking at it. I have also tried different versions of JDK inside the DOCKERFILE as that was the only obvious difference I could think of between my system and docker build environment, but that did not help.

Here are logs from when I execute the test manually myself, even via mvn clean package:

```
DEBUG CONSUMER getLatch before countdownjava.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@2932e15f[Count = 1]
DEBUG CONSUMER getLatch after countdownjava.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@2932e15f[Count = 0]
DEBUG TEST consumer.getLatch after await java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@2932e15f[Count = 0]
```

These are the logs containing separate hashes from docker build - mvn clean package

```
DEBUG CONSUMER getLatch before countdownjava.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@48d71ccf[Count = 1]
DEBUG CONSUMER getLatch after countdownjava.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@48d71ccf[Count = 0]
DEBUG TEST consumer.getLatch after await java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@7546033d[Count = 1]
```

And this is my current DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM maven:3.9.0-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine AS MAVEN_BUILD
COPY ./ ./
RUN mvn clean package
FROM openjdk:21-ea-jdk-slim
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /target/kafka-producer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /kafka-producer.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/kafka-producer.jar"]
```

Comment: Try making the latch volatile.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks for the tip, I like the idea, but unfortunately it did not help

Answer (score 1):

What helped me get these values accessed from the Test class was to make the latch variable `static`. Interestingly it was possible for the test to pass before, but only in about 1 out of 10 cases when run as part of `docker build` (10/10 when run any other way which still baffles me). With this keyword added, the test passed 10 out of 10 times.

10% success rate:

```
private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

100% success rate:

```
private static CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

I would be grateful if someone could still point me in the right direction to find out why is this behavior different in `docker build`, I can only think of the jdk mentioned in DOCKERFILE, maybe I'll try some more different ones